# Codenameone: Shadow is shown incorrect when an background image is used with transparency

Tags: codenameone

I use a container with RoundRectBorder and shadow. The Container is contained in another container which has an background image with transparency 128 (modifyAlpha((byte) 128)). When the form is initially shown, the shadow-part looks like as if the background-image has no transparency (attached image 1). After tapping on the screen or scrolling, the shadow is shown correct (attached image 2). Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

`RoundRectBorder` caches its appearance since rendering a shadow can be pretty expensive. I'm guessing this happens before the modify alpha call occurred.

Since `RoundRectBorder` can't detect changes to the underlying UI after the fact you are seeing this.  suggest placing the call to the modify alpha high or ideally avoiding it altogether and using an image that's already faded to white which will be cheaper in terms of CPU.